# Tabs with OnInitializedAsync?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Consider the following requirements:

- A page has [tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs).
- Each tab has a blazor component (ie. tab body) to display when clicked.
- Some tab bodies run `OnInitializedAsync` when initialized.
- A user can switch between tabs to display the different tab bodies.

But here is where the challenge comes in:

- A user make click a tab, switch to another tab, and switch back to the first tab they clicked.

  - (Eg. User clickes, the 1st tab, then switches to the 2nd tab, then goes back to the 1st tab again.)
- A tab body should not be initialized twice when it re-appears. (It should not run `OnInitializedAsync` twice).

How is this possible in blazor?

### Proposed Solution: Use @if to decide if each tab should render

Code:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" @onclick="() => tabId == 1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" @onclick="() => tabId == 2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" @onclick="() => tabId == 3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

@switch(tabId) 
{
    case 1:
        <Tab1Component />
        break;
    case 2:
        <Tab2Component />
        break;
    case 3:
        <Tab3Component />
        break;
}

@code {
    private int tabId = 1;
}
```

But this does not work since when I switch tabs, `OnInitializedAsync` gets called every time.

What would be helpful is if there is a `hidden` blazor attribute where I can just add an attribute to the tab bodies like this:

```html
<Tab1Component @hidden="tabId != 1" />
```

Answer (score 3):

> - A tab body should not be initialized twice when it re-appears. (It should not run OnInitializedAsync twice).

Blazor determnines when a Component is Initialized, your problem is actually "how to maintain state". Many ways to do that.

But I can see that a complex control with user input would be hard to restore.

> What would be helpful is if there is a hidden blazor attribute

You could make one. Your Tab1-3Component classes can expose a boolean and use CSS to set dispplay=none on the outer tag. I suppose you can't conditiopnaslly render because that would lose state again.

The `switch` statement would be replaced by

```
<Tab1Component Visible=(tabId==1) />
<Tab2Component Visible=(tabId==2) />
<Tab3Component Visible=(tabId==3) />
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found was to create a `Hidable` component:

**Hidable.razor.cs**

```cs
public partial class Hidable
{
    [Parameter] public bool? hidden { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool? show { get; set; }
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (hidden.HasValue && show.HasValue)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Do not set BOTH {nameof(hidden)} and {nameof(show)}!");
        }
    }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    private string style
    {
        get
        {
            if (hidden.HasValue && !hidden.Value) return "";
            if (show.HasValue && show.Value) return "";
            return "display: none";
        }
    }
}
```

**Hidable.razor**

```html
<div style="@style">@ChildContent</div>
```

**Example use**:

```html
<Hidable hidden="@(tabId == 1)">
    <Tab1Component />
</Hidable>
<Hidable hidden="@(tabId == 2)">
    <Tab2Component />
</Hidable>
<Hidable hidden="@(tabId == 3)">
    <Tab3Component />
</Hidable>
```

Comment: Thanks Henk. I fixed it.